# Result of nested SQL statements in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of `beats` and for each beat there are multiple rows containing different prices in the `pricing` table.

```
SELECT b.id, b.name,
(SELECT p.price FROM pricing as p WHERE p.license = 1 AND p.beat_id = b.id) as price_1,
(SELECT p.price FROM pricing as p WHERE p.license = 2 AND p.beat_id = b.id) as price_2
FROM beats as b 
WHERE b.added > 0 
AND b.active = 1 
AND b.deleted = 0 
AND price_1 > 0
ORDER BY b.id DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

I'm trying to make sure a `beat` is only retrieved when the `price_1` is greater than 0.

This doesn't work because you can't use the result of a nested SQL statement in a `WHERE` clause, but i've tried `HAVING price_1 > 0` and this doesn't work either.

How can I test  `price_1` and `price_2`?

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` without any aggregate functions?

Comment: @Barmar that was a copy/paste mistake, I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move that condition to a `having` clause.  This is a feature of MySQL and not supported by other databases:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name,
       (SELECT p.price FROM pricing as p WHERE p.license = 1 AND p.beat_id = b.id) as price_1,
       (SELECT p.price FROM pricing as p WHERE p.license = 2 AND p.beat_id = b.id) as price_2
FROM beats as b 
WHERE b.added > 0 AND b.active = 1 AND b.deleted = 0 
GROUP BY b.producer 
HAVING price_1 > 0
ORDER BY b.id DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Ah right that works now after putting `HAVING` after the `GROUP BY` - I was putting it just before. Thanks for your help...feel silly now!

Comment: @JohnRuddell I always accept the right answers, but this got answered so quick SO didn't let me do it straight away.

Comment: Ah ok cool.. i just wanted to be sure because there are some people that do that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JOIN:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, p1.price AS price_1, p2.price AS price_2
FROM beats AS b
JOIN pricing AS p1 ON p1.beat_id = b.id
JOIN pricing AS p2 ON p2.beat_id = b.id
WHERE b.added > 0 AND b.active = 1 AND b.deleted = 0
  AND p1.license = 1 AND p1.price > 0
  AND p2.licence = 2
GROUP BY b.producer
ORDER BY b.id DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of the DML for your tables (for example it is not clear why you need to `group by b.producer` given that `b.id` looks like a primary key) the minimal change is to pull the nested query into a subquery and do an inner join on it

```
SELECT b.id, b.name,
       p1.price as price_1,
       (SELECT p.price FROM pricing as p WHERE p.license = 2 AND p.beat_id = b.id) as price_2
  FROM beats as b
       JOIN pricing p1 ON (p1.license = 1 AND p1.beat_id = b.id AND p1.price > 0) 
 WHERE b.added > 0 
   AND b.active = 1 
   AND b.deleted = 0 
GROUP BY b.producer 
ORDER BY b.id DESC 
LIMIT 50
```

Assuming that `b.id` is the primary key I would also drop the `group by b.producer` and it is probably sensible to pull the price_2 query into a join (though again without more knowledge of your data and DML I cannot say for definite if it should be an inner or left outer join).